# android.View.WindowLeaked window com.android.internal.policy Exception

Tags: java, android, mysql, json, database

I am trying to fetch data from MySql server and display it in my listview.

**Parser.java**

```
    public class Parser extends AsyncTask<Void,Integer,Integer> {
    Context c;
    ListView lv;
    String data;
   String arr[];
    ArrayList<String> players=new ArrayList<>();
    ProgressDialog pd;
    public Parser(Context c, String data, ListView lv) {
        this.c = c;
        this.data = data;
        this.lv = lv;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pd=new ProgressDialog(c);
        pd.setTitle("Parser");
        pd.setMessage("Parsing ....Please wait");
        pd.show();
    }
    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {
        return this.parse();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer integer) {
        super.onPostExecute(integer);
        if(integer == 1)
        {
            //ADAPTER
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(c,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,players);
            //ADAPT TO LISTVIEW
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
            //LISTENET
            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    Toast.makeText(c,players.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    //Snackbar.make(view,players.get(position),Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();;
                }
            });
        }else
        {
            Toast.makeText(c,"Unable to Parse",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        pd.dismiss();
    }
    //PARSE RECEIVED DATA
    private int parse()
    {
        try
        {
            //ADD THAT DATA TO JSON ARRAY FIRST

            JSONArray ja=new JSONArray(data);
            //CREATE JO OBJ TO HOLD A SINGLE ITEM
            JSONObject jo=null;


            players.clear();
            //LOOP THRU ARRAY
            for(int i=0;i<ja.length();i++)
            {
                jo=ja.getJSONObject(i);
                //RETRIEVE NAME
                String name=jo.getString("Name");
                //ADD IT TO OUR ARRAYLIST
                players.add(name);

             jo = ja.getJSONObject(i);
               String pposition = jo.getString("Position");
              arr[i] = pposition;


            }
            return 1;
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
 String url="http://bookvilla.esy.es/book.php";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
          final ListView lv= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
        final Downloader d=new Downloader(this,url,lv);
        d.execute();


    }
}
```

I would like to mention one thing that when i try to fetch only "Name" its working perfectly...but when i add these lines :

> jo = ja.getJSONObject(i);
>                  String pposition = jo.getString("Position");
>                  arr[i] = pposition;

Exception starts appearing

**Error log**
[image]

Kindly help.

Comment: try using the application context:  `final Downloader d=new Downloader(this.getApplicationContext(),url,lv);`

Comment: @rafsanahmad007  now the exception has changed to java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ee/com.example.ee.MainActivity}: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application